# JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:

Tags: python, json, dictionary, load, typeerror

i'm trying to load "data.json" Dictionary in a file, I'm watching a tutorial video for that which uses the code on below to do it and it works but when i do the same I get the typeError.
could you please what's wrong with mycode?

```
import json 
data = json.load(open("data.json", 'r')) print(data)
```

> JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
> 0)

Comment: use `json.load` to read from a file. You used `loads` which parses an already loaded string.

Comment: I did but I got a new error that I've written.

Comment: That usually means that the file is empty. Try `print(open("data.json", mode="rb").read())` (note the "rb") and see. If its `b''`, then there is no data to read.

Comment: I've got b' ' ! so the file is empty, how can i fix it up? do i need to install any pip or import sth else?

Comment: Not sure how I can help you there. If you just want test data, you can write basic python types to the file. How about of a dict of lists with integers? `json.dump({"one":[1], "two":[2], "three":[3]}, open("test.json", "w"))`? It'll read back.

Comment: i've got None as an output

Comment: `json.dump` returns `None` but writes the file. You should be able to do the open / read thing again and see it.

Comment: ok thanks alot, problem solved! I'll make my own file in this way and will work on it instead of data.jason.